# How to create unreadable files in linux

Tags: linux, system, ubuntu-12.04, system-administration

I have a configuration file with me and want to make the file unreadable to others.

What can be done with it?

Encryption is a way to do it but Encryption makes the file uninstallable in Linux platform.

Comment: Unreadable files? Well, write an IOCCC entry. That's unreadable.

Comment: *"But Encryption makes the file uninstallable in Linux platform."* Who told you that? A unix file is a bag of bytes. What they represent is your business.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the readable mode bit for others

```
chmod o-r file.txt
```

or set the umask at creation time appropriately

```
umask 027
```

this turns off the `w` bit for the group and `rwx` bits for others, when you create a new file.

If it should be readable for the software only, you can set the permissions to

```
chmod 0400 file.conf
```

or with umask

```
umask 0377
```

Which is the same as `-r--------`.
For this to work, the file must have the same userid as the software process reading it.

Comment: Well its a conf file. So the operation is not permitted.

Comment: i want the File to be permanently unreadable to humans but only readable to the OS concerned because it is a part of a software

Comment: @dino It must be readable somehow, so the minimum permission would be `r` for the user (your software). Please see updated answer.

Comment: The 0400 stills opens the file.. I want the file not to be opened by any of the user(except root) and this setting should be permanent..